# A map of a compact connected manifold with non-empty boundary to a sphere of the same dimension is null-homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres

In Milnor & Kervaire's *Groups of Homotopy Spheres* paper, this claim:

> A map of a compact connected manifold with non-empty boundary to a sphere of the same dimension is null-homotopic

is made without justification or reference. Can anyone see why is it true?

All I can think of is that compact manifolds with non-empty boundary have top homology $0$, so this map induces $0$ in all homology groups (except the $0$th, of course). However, this doesn't seem to help. It's easy to see that the map restricted to the boundary is null-homotopic (since it can't be surjective there, say by Sard's theorem), but that also doesn't seem to help. Any explanations / references are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A connected compact smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ with nonempty boundary deformation to a simplicial complex where all cells have dimension at most $n-1$. [See this answer by Lee Mosher for a proof.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/92723/36146) The basic idea, as far as I understand, is to remove the boundary to get a noncompact manifold, take a triangulation of the resulting manifold, and then shrink all the $n$-cells starting "from the outside" (like when you deformation retract $[0,\infty)$ onto $\{0\}$) – this last part is rather tricky and the first version of my answer was a bit naive, thanks to Lee Mosher for giving me a link to the full proof.

And now by cellular approximation, a map from a simplicial complex of dimension $\le n-1$ to $S^n$ is nullhomotopic, because you can consider a CW-complex structure on $S^n$ where the $(n-1)$-skeleton is just a point.

(I used a triangulation here, I'm not sure it's strictly necessary... Maybe there's an easier argument.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't really see how to fill in the details to this argument. We can't contract one simplex at a time, because it may share a face with another simplex, and we'd have to contract those at the same time; so the process of shrinking the simplices that have faces in the boundary doesn't seem so trivial. Furthermore, how do I know when to stop contracting them? I suppose eventually I'll be contracting simplices in pairs which share a lower dimensional face, so that everything gets squished one dimension lower (easy to imagine this in an annulus), but it seems ---

Comment: far from obvious to prove that it'll work out in general, unless I'm mistaken. Can you indicate how to fill those details, or give a reference?

Comment: The manifold $M$ actually deformation retracts to an $n-1$-dimensional simplicial complex. See my answer to this very closely related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces/92723#92723. The proof there is written for a noncompact 2-manifold, but the proof applies to a compact manifold with boundary (strip the boundary away) and it generalizes with very little change to any dimension.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for this! I knew the proof worked but clearly my memory of it was off. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pedro See the link Lee Mosher gave above.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Just for the record: The reference in the PL category to the result that each open manifold is h.e. to its codimension 1 skeleton is: Whitehead, J. H. C. The immersion of an open 3-manifold in euclidean 3-space. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 11 (1961) 81–90. (I think, it was Whitehead's very last paper, before he died.) With (much) more effort, this also work in the topological category: Each open topological n-manifold is homotopy-equivalent to an n-1 dimensional CW complex. This can be proved using Kirby-Siebenmann (dimension >4), Quinn (dim 4), Moise (dim <4).

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the fact that such a manifold has no top-dimensional cohomology.

Note that one can construct a $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ from $S^n$ by gluing on cells of dimension at least $n + 2$ to kill the higher homotopy groups. So the $(n+1)$-skeleton of this $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$, denoted $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)^{(n+1)}$, is $S^n$. As Eilenberg-MacLane spaces represent cohomology, for any $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ we have

$$H^n(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong [M, K(\mathbb{Z}, n)] \cong [M, K(\mathbb{Z}, n)^{(n+1)}] \cong [M, S^n]$$

where we use cellular approximation in the second step. Therefore, if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold which is not closed, every map $M \to S^n$ is nullhomotopic.